# .map is not a function when getting React files from build folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a node/express application that's using `React` for the frontend. Everything works fine in development mode where there's a proxy between the backend running on `localhost:5000` and the frontend on `localhost:3000`. However, I'm running into an  issue for my production build where I'm getting the static React files from the `build` folder by including the following in my main server file:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile("index.html", {
    root: path.join(__dirname, "client", "build"),
  });
});
```

With this setup, I'm able to see the React app on `localhost:5000`, but on certain routes/pages I receive `TypeError: a.map is not a function`. The errors all seem to be triggered by arrays that are created in a `context` provider that sets state from APIs using `axios`. Here's an example of one of the API calls:

```
  const getNodesApi = {
    url: "model/get-all-nodes",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      token: localStorage.token,
    },
  };
  async function getNodeData() {
    await axiosPm(getNodesApi)
      .then((response) => {
        const resData = response.data;
        setNodeData(resData);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
  }
```

Is there something I have to do to set the base URL for the APIs or could something else be causing the `TypeError: a.map is not a function`?

****Edit 1:** Example where .map is failing**

```
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(
    processes.map((process, index) => ({
      key: index,
      value: process.process_id,
      label: process.process_name,
    }))
  );
```

In this example `processes` is coming from the `context` provider. It's initially defined by:

```
const [processes, setProcesses] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Can include an example of the code where `.map` is failing? It's likely you are using a property in a response that is undefined or not an array, something along those lines.

Comment: @Matt see the `Edit 1` in the post. If the property was undefined or not an array, then wouldn't I see the same failure in development using a proxy?

Comment: There's always something a little bit different :) How is the `processes` state being set?

Comment: @Matt it's being set in an `async` function similar to the `getNodeData` from my main post, which is included in a `useEffect` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for visibility. The issue was being caused because I was mounting my backend/API routes after doing `app.get` for the React `index.html`. To resolve, mount the backend routes first.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));

//Routes - mounted from backend for API
mountRoutes(app);

//Routes - use from React app for frontend
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile("index.html", {
    root: path.join(__dirname, "client", "build"),
  });
});
```