# 'TypeError a.map is not a function' in Npm run build, but not npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, build, production

I have a basic MERN stack application. On the app when I do npm start, it runs fine and functions as expected. However, after doing a npm run build, and running serve -s build, the app fails with the following message -

```
TypeError: a.map is not a function
at He (Contacts.js:27:16)
at wl (react-dom.production.min.js:166:137)
at Pi (react-dom.production.min.js:215:270)
at wu (react-dom.production.min.js:291:202)
at ys (react-dom.production.min.js:279:389)
at vs (react-dom.production.min.js:279:320)
at ms (react-dom.production.min.js:279:180)
at as (react-dom.production.min.js:270:88)
at rs (react-dom.production.min.js:267:429)
at x (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
```

Here is my express main server.js file -

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const connectDB = require('./config/db')

app.use(cors())

//Connect database
connectDB()

//Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => 
    res.json({ msg: 'Welcome to the Digital RoloDex API'}))


//Define Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'))
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'))
app.use('/api/contacts', require('./routes/contacts'))

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4444
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`app running on ${PORT}`))
```

Here is the file where the error is coming from -

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import ContactItem from './ContactItem'
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner'
import { getContacts, useContacts } from '../context/contact/ContactState'

const Contacts = () => {
    const [ contactState, contactDispatch ] = useContacts()
    const { contacts, filtered, loading } = contactState
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getContacts(contactDispatch)
        
    }, [contactDispatch])

    if (contacts === 0 && !loading) {
        return <h4>Please add a contact</h4>
    }

    return (
        <div>
        { contacts !== null && !loading ? 
           filtered.length !== 0 ? 
             filtered.map((contact) => (
                        <ContactItem key={contact._id} contact={contact} />
                  ))
                : contacts.map((contact) => (
                        <ContactItem key={contact._id} contact={contact} />
                        
                  )) 
            :
          <Spinner />
        }       
        </div>
    )
}

export default Contacts
```

I found two stackoverflow questions with the same problem. I applied their tips, but it is not helping either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65069848/typeerror-a-map-is-not-a-function
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362803/map-is-not-a-function-when-getting-react-files-from-build-folder
```

Comment: Are you sure if `contacts` is a list?

Comment: @taipei yeah I figured it out. Thanks for getting back with me.

Answer (score 1):

I want to answer my own question just in case someone runs into the same error. Foremost, in a static build, any variables, components, functions, etc. are going to be renamed with abbreviated letters. Which is why it is stating "a".map is not a function.

In addition, my backend and client were in two separate folders. So my front end wasn't calling to my back end properly. I uninstalled cors since this would make my users' information vulnerable across the web. Instead, I put my backend folder and files in the root and kept the client in its own folder. From there, I cd. into my client folder and did an npm run build. The error went away and was able to call back to the express api.

Comment: The same, but I can not get the answer of how to solve the "n.map is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

I would like to weigh in here as I had a similar issue that plagued me for many hours. Just like the original poster, I was experiencing a '... is not a function' issue in my npm build but not my npm start dev environment. However, in my case, it was caused by Squel.js objects. To fix this, I upgraded my nodeJS version and ran npm audit. This fixed my issue, the commands I used are below.

```
nvm install node
nvm use node
npm audit fix --force
```

Once I did that, I was able to rebuild my react app with no errors